# How can the cursor goes to next text field when i press key Enter?

Tags: jsp, enter, onkeypress

This is my `login.jsp` page,here i have 2 text fields when i enter user name in first text field and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from keyboard it is not going to next text field.how can i do this? thanks for your help.

```
<body>         
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <table width="90%" border="0" align="center"  cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" > 
        <tr> 
            <td width="15%"><input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="username"/></td> 
            <td><input name="password" type="password" id="password" value="password"/></td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr><td>
                &nbsp;
            </td></tr>
        <tr> 
            <td align="right"  valign="bottom" ><input type="button"  name= "button"  id= "button"   value= "Submit"   /></td> 
        </tr> 
    </table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change focus to another inputtext people usually hit tab instead of enter..

However you can do that with jquery event handler..

```
$( "#your-username-input" ).keypress(function( event ) {
//press enter button
if ( event.which == 13 ) {
 $( "#your-other-input" ).focus();
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply,other than jquery how can i do that with javascript?

Comment: HTML:   `<input id="username" type="text" onkeypress="EnterPressed(event)" />`  
Javascript:
`function EnterPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("password").focus();
    }
}`

It should be like that, maybe there will be some typo.. ^^
Thanks for the accept..

Comment: [DOM focus() article](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp)

There you go, please paste your code and make sure you write the right element ID..

Answer (score 0):

Two options for web browsers:

1. ### ***You can press TAB instead***
2. you can reprogram your keyboard with the tab key where the enter key is ;) ;)

Answer (score 0):

$("#username").on('keydown', function(event) {

```
if(event.which == 13) {// Enter key pressed

     event.preventDefault();

     /* $this = $(this);

     $this.focus();

     var value = $this.val();

     $this.val(''); // clear the field 

     // do stuff with the value*/

     }
```

});

Same will be for the password

Comment: thanks for reply,other than jquery how can i do that with javascript?

Comment: just u have to change $("#username").on('keydown', function(event) { with function clk(obj) and in html code and onclick = clk(this)